# Access data in Firebase from android only if user authenticated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

[image]

My firebase data looks like this. I want to access the data of **salon->1** I can access that -

```
    databaseReference = mDatabase.child("salon").child("1").child("franchises");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

But in this case the data is not secure cay body can ready write data so I try to add a rule like this -

```
{
 "rules": {
   "users": {
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
    }
   }
  }
}
```

But now I am getting `permission denied` in android when I try to access the data. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior when nothing is specified is that a user is not allowed to read data. You're not setting any permission on `salon`, so Firebase rejects the read.

To grant read permission, you'll have to also specify who can read the data under the `salon` node. For example, to allow users to read all salon data:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "salon": {
       ".read": "auth != null"
     }
   },
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok and what about calling the franchises should I need to pass the uid that I got after authentication?

Comment: Like this -     databaseReference = mDatabase.child("salon").child("1").child("franchises/"+uid);

Comment: Ah... the salon's are per user? That was not clear. I've updated my answer. Note it's a *very* bad practice to store passwords in plain text in the database, so I hope the values are [salted hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

Comment: No the concept is One salon have multiple franchises. And user should be able to see all the salon franchises and book a slot. I am new in firebase I am not sure how I should design the structure. I am open for your suggestion.

In my mobile app I am using firebase authentication I want to only give the access to all those user how are authenticated user. That's my main aim.

Comment: in that case my previous rules were what you needed. I reverted the edit.

Comment: But in this case as an anonymous user anybody can read my data am I right

Comment: I want to make the salon data is only available to those user who are registered in our system, I don't want any one can access them with anonymous token.